# Finding net torque from dimensional torques

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

$F = ma$, and if I have acceleration vectors in 3D it's easy enough to just find $|a| = ||a_x + a_y + a_z||$, so I can find |F| = m|a|. Great.

How can I do the analogous thing with rotational vectors? I know $\tau = I\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is rotational acceleration and $I$ is the rotational moment in that direction. I have three component moments, $I_x, I_y, I_z$, and three rotational accelerations, $\alpha_x, \alpha_y, \alpha_z$. How can I find $|\tau|$?

Comment: The moment of inertia is not a vector.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it is possible to have different moments around different axes of rotation.

Comment: Do you mean to say your moment of inertia tensor is diagonal?

Comment: "For a general three-dimensional body, it is *always* possible to find 3 mutually orthogonal axis (an x,y,z coordinate system) for which the products of inertia are zero, and the inertia matrix takes a diagonal form." https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec26.pdf

So yes, I guess that is what I mean.

Comment: You know that $$\boldsymbol{\tau} =\left( \mathbf{R} \mathbf{I}_{\rm body} \mathbf{R}^\top \right) \boldsymbol{\alpha} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \left( \mathbf{R} \mathbf{I}_{\rm body} \mathbf{R}^\top \right) \boldsymbol{\omega}$$ is the correct vector form of the rotational equations of motion, so what is the point of estimated $\| \boldsymbol{\tau} \|$ before doing the math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations of motion in vector form are $$ \boldsymbol{\tau} = \mathbf{I} \boldsymbol{\alpha} + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{I} \boldsymbol{\omega} $$

In component form the equation above is

$$ \begin{vmatrix}\tau_{x}\\
\tau_{y}\\
\tau_{z}
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx} & -I_{xy} & -I_{xz}\\
-I_{xy} & I_{yy} & -I_{yz}\\
-I_{xz} & -I_{yz} & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}\alpha_{x}\\
\alpha_{y}\\
\alpha_{z}
\end{vmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0 & -\omega_{z} & \omega_{y}\\
\omega_{z} & 0 & -\omega_{x}\\
-\omega_{y} & \omega_{x} & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx} & -I_{xy} & -I_{xz}\\
-I_{xy} & I_{yy} & -I_{yz}\\
-I_{xz} & -I_{yz} & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}\omega_{x}\\
\omega_{y}\\
\omega_{z}
\end{vmatrix} $$

and so to get $\| \boldsymbol{\tau} \|$ you literally have to do the math (linear algebra).

Of course, you have to transform the MMOI matrix from body coordinates to the inertial reference frame first with

$$ \mathbf{I} = \mathbf{R}\, \mathbf{I}_{\rm body} \mathbf{R}^\top $$ where $\mathbf{R}$ is the 3×3 rotation matrix.

where $\mathbf{I}_{\rm body} = \begin{bmatrix}I_{1}\\
 & I_{2}\\
 &  & I_{3}
\end{bmatrix}$ are the three principal mass moment of inertia values.

Alternatively, you can find the moment of inertia $I_{\rm axis}$ about a specific direction. Then if the rotation is about a fixed axis (say the direction $\boldsymbol{n}$) then $$\boxed{ \tau_{\rm axis} = I_{\rm axis} \alpha_{\rm axis}}$$ To get $I_{\rm axis}$ from the 3×3 mass moment of inertia tensor $\mathbf{I}$ you do the following:

$$ I_{\rm axis} = \boldsymbol{n} \cdot (\mathbf{I} \boldsymbol{n}) $$ where $\cdot$ is the vector dot product, and $\boldsymbol{n}$ is a *unit* direction vector.

Comment: I asked for the formula to find overall torque magnitude. This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I read your question on how to get from the three MMOI values to a single value so you can do a scalar operation between torque and acceleration.

Comment: $\tau = I\alpha$ in 1D, yes. What is the derivation for the second term? We don't say $F = ma + mv^2$ when we go from 1D to 3D.

Comment: Torque is the derivative of momentum $\boldsymbol{L} = \mathbf{I} \boldsymbol{\omega}$. The derivative on a rotating frame involves a second term which is $\boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{L}$. Google search "derivative on rotating frame".

Comment: So the last term is a 'fictitious force'? http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node56.html  If I only care about energy expended, then is it sufficient to just use the body's reference frame and only the first part of the equation? Then if $I_{body}$ is diagonal, $|\tau| = ||[I_x\alpha_x, I_y\alpha_y, I_z\alpha_z]||$

Comment: It is not a fictitious force, because it is not a force. It is the moment required for the conservation of angular momentum, also known as a gyroscopic moment. Second, if body MMOI is diagonal when resolved into the inertial reference frame $\mathbf{I}$ is a full 3×3 matrix still. Lastly if you want energy, you integrate power which is $$P=\boldsymbol{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{I} \boldsymbol{\omega}$$